What is the difference between tip, trick and hack?
For a native speaker is there a difference between tip, trick and hack?

What's a tip for making a delicious omelette?
What's a trick for making… ?
Do you know a hack for making… ?


Unlawfully breaking into a computer system is a recent use of the word hack which had the meaning "quick and inelegant solution" long before computers arrived on the scene. In the context of making an omelette I doubt there's any ambiguity regarding legality, unless it involved undercooking the eggs in a restaurant setting :-)  A trick can be elegant. A hack can't.  What a hack lacks in elegance it often makes up for in cleverness.

dress an omelet? Generally, one says make an omelet...I don't know what that means. hack is either journalism or IT but not cooking.

@Lambie "hack" has been generalized, e.g. lifehack.

This question could be improved by talking about what you found in dictionaries so that unclarity in those entries could be addressed.

@Barmar lifehack here? For an omelet?

@Lambie No. It was just an example of another context where "hack" is used, not journalism or IT. I don't know the jargon used by chefs, but I can easily imagine them using "hack" to mean clever cooking techniques, just as programmers use it for clever technology.

FYI, all three of your examples would be much more idiomatic if you replaced to make an omelet by for making omelets.

You are supposed to look up words in dictionaries (basic research) before asking a question: Merriam-Webster characterises a hack as "clever" and a trick as "quick or artful". (Note that another related meaning of "tip" is "a piece of advance or confidential information given by one thought to have access to special or inside sources", often with regards to gambling on sports.)

@StuartF: I did that indeed. In the meantime I've found a complete explanation on linguee. So if you want to delete that so badly written question, it's ok for me, and I apologize for the disturbance and the time you all spent telling me how much it was wrong.

@mins +1 I feel the question is a good one for learners as it makes them understand the difference. There is some concern raised about the word "hack" and how it is related to "tip" and  trick. And also some jokes on omelette. Interestingly I found a sentence with egg in it in the dictionary. Try this hack for cooking a perfect egg in a microwave.

A tip is a piece of advice that is considered in some sense minor or simple. Tips can be about anything. One might offer a tip about a trick.
In the context of your examples, trick and hack are essentially synonymous, though hack can be mildly derogatory, and sometimes one uses it in a self-deprecating manner.

Hollandaise sauce would be one common way to dress an omelet. It's more common to talk of dressing a salad, though, since salads really need some kind of dressing.

OP's query:

What is the difference between tip, trick and hack?

Let's check the dictionary and find out the meanings of each word.
I. Dictionary meaning of tip, trick and hack.
The three words have distinct meanings.

Reference Cambridge dictionary.
1. tip noun [C] (INFORMATION) B1
a useful piece of information especially about how to do something:
gardening/cooking/sewing tips.
give someone a tip about/for something
She gave me a useful/helpful/valuable/practical tip about/for growing tomatoes.
2. trick noun [C] (METHOD) B2
an effective or quick way of doing something:
trick to
What's the trick to getting this chair to fold up?
On page 21, some tricks to speed up your beauty routine.
3. hack noun [C] (HELP) informal.
a good solution or piece of advice:
I found a great online community of users sharing tips and hacks for the app.
Improve your fitness routine with one simple hack.
Try this hack for cooking a perfect egg in a microwave.

II. Difference between tip, trick and hack..
1. Tip: provides general guidance or advice. It is usually widely applicable.
2. Trick: reveals specific techniques or methods. It often requires some skill.
3. Hack: offers clever solutions. It is usually innovative.
III. Tips, tricks and hacks for making an omelette..
1. Tips:.

Eggs should be at room temperature for easier whisking.
Butter or oil should be applied to the pan to prevent sticking.

2. Tricks:

Pan should be tilted and rotated to distribute the eggs evenly.
To get a good texture, cook over medium heat.

3. Hacks:

You can use leftover cooked vegetables or meat.
For easy removal, use silicone mat.
For evenly cooked and crisper omelette, cook it in a Panini Press.


Each of those words can mean a way of getting a specific task done, as in your example. But each also has different meanings, usages and connotations that the others don't.
You can read a dictionary to find all the different meanings of each word, and you can listen to how and when native speakers use each of them in different situations.
